# JavaScriptInterface class is never called to load html on webview android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i am parsing an xml file and loading it on web view with Java script Interface class along with CSS but my Java script interface class is never called and no content is loaded on the web view, the app just crashes and no error is given on log cat. could you friends help solve this.

my js interface class is

```
    public class JsInterface {
public String wordDef;

public String addData(){
    Log.v("JSInterface", ""+wordDef);
    return wordDef;
}
```

and i am calling in the main activity like

```
                 JsInterface Jsi = new JsInterface();
            Jsi.wordDef = content;
            Log.v("Content",""+content);
            wv.addJavascriptInterface(Jsi, "interfaces");
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ccc.html");
```

my html looks like

```
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
         <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=WIDTH_OF_YOUR_PAGE, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
           <title>Untitled Document</title>
         <link href="word_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
    function addData(){
    //var data = getQuerystring('word');
    var data = window.interfaces.addData();
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
}
```

Comment: @RomanBlack  added the html code

Answer (score 0):

well I havent take a look at your code but let me tell you this, if you dont make a constructor for your class and pass the reference od context to the constructor javascript is never gonna be able to call any method of java

Answer (score 0):

try this:
            JsInterface Jsi = new JsInterface();
            Jsi.wordDef = content;
            Log.v("Content",""+content);
            wv.addJavascriptInterface(Jsi, "interfaces");
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ccc.html");

```
       public class JsInterface {
       public String wordDef;
       Context mContext;

       public void JsInterface(Context c){
       mContext = c;
       }

       public String addData(){
       Log.v("JSInterface", ""+wordDef);
       return wordDef;
       }

       }
```

then calling from javascript

```
        function addData(){
           var data = interfaces.addData();
       }
```

it should work